# Get all images from website has block calls

Tags: c#

I'm trying get all images from page:

```
  public async Task<PhotoURL> GetImagePortal()
        {  
            strLinkPage = "http://www.propertyguru.com.sg/listing/19077438";
            var lstString = new List<string>();
            int itotal = default(int);          
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            string strHtml = await client.GetStringAsync(strLinkPage);
            doc.LoadHtml(strHtml);
            var pageHtml = doc.DocumentNode;
            if (pageHtml != null)
            {
                var projectRoot = pageHtml.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@class,'submain')]");
                //var projectChild = projectRoot.SelectSingleNode("div/div[2]");
                var imgRoot = projectRoot.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@class,'white-bg-padding')]");
                var imgChilds = imgRoot.SelectNodes("div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li");               
                itotal = imgChilds.Count();
                foreach (var imgItem in imgChilds)    
                {
                    string linkImage = imgItem.SelectSingleNode("img").Attributes["src"].Value;
                    lstString.Add(linkImage);
                }
            }
            return await Task.Run(() => new PhotoURL { total = itotal, URL = lstString });
        }
```

at line

```
 string strHtml = await client.GetStringAsync(strLinkPage);
```

i have error 405 method not allowed.
I try using 
    WebClient, HTTPWebRequest.
help me, please!

Comment: You may ultimately be interested in getting all images, but your title is unrelated to the actual question, which is more like "Why am I getting 405 method not allowed for a get of webpage?"

Answer (score 1):

The site required a user-agent and since you are just using a HttpClient without any options, the site does not think it is a correct request (It does not look like it's coming from a browser without the user agent).

Try this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();    
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36");
```

Or if you prefer any other user agents strings.

Comment: thanks for reply [tag:Merryweather].
i try using your code into my code, but it  has return header html without body html